# Trouble viewing environment variables in bash terminal on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial (Mac version): https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html which talks about setting environmental variables so I don't have to hardcode my SID and other important information from my Twilio account.

When I type in $ Atom .bashrc in the terminal, it opens up Atom which I then therefore place this code in:

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=youraccountsid
```

I changed the 'youraccountsid' to my actual SID number, but when I try to echo from terminal:

```
echo $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
```

No SID number is shown and I get the following instead:

```
My-MacBook-Air:Users shawnm$ echo $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
...This area is skipped/black...
My-MacBook-Air:Users shawnm$
```

Any help with what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: You edited this export command into your .bashrc, so now you have to run a new shell. The current shell doesn't know this yet.

Comment: I was able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS bash will always read in `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`.

Within the terminal I ran:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

The text editor will open which I then pasted in the following:

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=youraccountsid
```

Save the program and then command + q to quit the text editor. From there, I typed in:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you're able to view the variables by echoing:

```
echo $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
```